# OS X: can I create a skeleton for the guest user, new users?

Tags: macos, mac, user-accounts

When login in as guest or creating a new user, can I have a skeleton home folder (akin to /etc/skel on other unixes) pre-filled with files, and having some customized preferences?

Otherwise, is there any other way to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Mac OS X stores the equivelant of /etc/skel in /System/Library/User\ Template/English.lproj

http://www.cs.dixie.edu/ldap/server/ldap/final_ldap.php